# Fatal Error while trying to detect swap signature

Tags: linux, centos, vmware

I've installed CentOS 6.5 On VMWare Workstation.
I added a SCSI Virtual Disk (.vmdk) to this Machine when it was Powered On.
I decided to store the Disk as a single file & allocated all disk space at once.

I try to run pvcreate /dev/sdb & I get the following error message.

```
[root@localhost dev]# pvcreate /dev/sdb
  /dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
  /dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 21474770944: Input/output error
  /dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 21474828288: Input/output error
  /dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
  Fatal error while trying to detect swap signature on /dev/sdb.
```

I've looked up this error on Google but got nowhere with the first few [search results](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=fatal%20error%20while%20trying%20to%20detect%20swap%20signature%20on&oq=fata&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j0l2.1047j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).
Can someone please help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1):

your Virtual disk is not in active state,  Once you rebooted its came to active state.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with a reboot of the Virutal Machine. After reboot, I was able to run

pvcreate /dev/sdb successfully.

Any idea what happened after a reboot. I'd like to know more on why a reboot resolved the issue.